# Why dont Backbone models work correctly when using CoffeeScript class inheritance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have seen several posts about how you can use CoffeeScript's extends functionality with Backbone, but I cant get it to work.  The following code:

```
Backbone = require 'Backbone'

# The backbone way
Base = Backbone.Model.extend (
    initialize: ->
)

Model  = Base.extend (

    initialize: ->
        console.log 'initialize called'
        @on 'change:foo', ->
            console.log 'foo changed (Base)'

    defaults: (
        foo: 'bar'
    )
)

model = new Model()
model.set 'foo', 'baz'
console.log model.get 'foo'



# The coffeescript way with double ineritance
class Base2 extends Backbone.Model
    constructor: ->

class Model2 extends Base2

    constructor: ->
        console.log 'constructor called (Base2)'
        @on 'change:foo', ->
            console.log 'foo changed (Base2)'

    defaults: (
        foo: 'bar'
    )

model2 = new Model2 (foo: 'bar')

model2.set 'foo', 'baz2'
console.log model2.get 'foo'
```

Throws:

```
  % coffee index.coffee                                                                                                                                                                            
initialize called
foo changed (Base)
baz
constructor called (Base2)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
  at Model2._.extend.set
```

You can also play around with it here http://codepen.io/guyht/pen/LEOdZr?editors=001

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're replacing Backbone's constructor by specifying your own `constructor`. Backbone needs to use its own constructor to set up all the Backbone internals, your constructor-like code should be in `initialize` just like when you use Backbone's `extend` function instead of CoffeeScript's `extends` keyword:

```
class Base2 extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: ->

class Model2 extends Base2

    initialize: ->
        console.log 'initialize called (Base2)'
        @on 'change:foo', ->
            console.log 'foo changed (Base2)'

    defaults: (
        foo: 'bar'
    )
```

Updated demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myqxWY

Comment: Been playing around with this a bit more, and indeed it works when i use initialize (not constructor), but I still find it odd that I have to implement an initialize function in order for the model to work.  It seems to me that using the default _.extends is going to be more reliable.

Comment: @mrwooster You don't have to implement an initialize function, you just have to **not** override the constructor. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPOEQa works fine without initialize defined. I suspect you'd see the same issue if you override the constructor with _.extend

Comment: @mrwooster Not writing your own constructor is quite common with frameworks, happens all the time.

Comment: @ivarni - yes, I get that, but my question was more around **why** the constructor function will interfere with the initialize function when they appear to be two separate functions....

Comment: @mrwooster They are two separate functions. The initialize is there for you to hook into and set things up, the constructor is there for the framework to set its own stuff up. When you override the constructor you have to either call the original constructor or reverse engineer it. Overriding it and leaving it blank will, as you discovered, break things. This is what the default constructor you were overriding does: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L338. Note that it creates the `attributes` object, which was missing when your code blew up at `model2.set()`